# Tag merge / synonym request: [legacy-code] → [legacy]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [legacy-code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legacy-code) (2 questions) into [legacy](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legacy) (46), and make them synonyms.

Tag *legacy-code* does not have wiki nor excerpt. Tag *legacy* wiki excerpt is

> Questions about legacy languages, code, or applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I agree.

Legacy can have a different meaning when being used to describe the old application during an application rewrite project.

Example:

> What columns are we supposed to display on the Inventory Summary panel again?  What does the legacy application have?

Legacy code I feel is just describing or talking about old code in an application.  Granted the example questions you have posted are tagged legacy but actually about legacy code.

What I suggest instead is to create [legacy-application](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legacy-application) instead.

Comment: my request is based on tag wiki excerpt wording, which clearly indicates for all the readers: "Questions about **legacy** languages, **code**, or **applications**." While it is spelled the way it is now, separate tag [tag:legacy-code] makes no sense

Comment: I think it makes sense if we change the excerpt wording to be specific.  Either we create separate tags for code and applications or we get rid of the legacy-code tag.

Comment: if we change excerpt, then we also probably need to re-scan existing questions in that tag to find out if some of these became invalidated, right? (side note having 2 or 3 encounters with legacy through my career I feel _applications_ and _code_ in these matters are pretty tightly coupled)

Comment: @gnat Well they are tightly coupled but still different.  I have a few experiences where conversations arise that product owners want old legacy software to be rewritten, but are confused about which features need to carry over.